# Complex responsive layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a complex layout design and I want to make it responsive. The problem is I don't know-

1. How I should approach this design (how to structure the html to achieve this)

   - flex?
   - grid?
   - absolute positioning?
2. Is it even possible to make this kind of layout without making 2 sets of everything and hiding one of them for desktop and vice versa?

This is the layout that I'm talking about:

Desktop layout

[image: Desktop layout]

Mobile layout

[image: Mobile layout]

I don't even need the code part for this implementation.

I just need to know if this is possible and if so how do I do that(which structure, what display type for the parent etc)
If not, what are the work arounds?

Changing the design is the final resort but i really don't want to do that.

Comment: You can do it with CSS flexbox.

Comment: @Momin I've tried that but the yellow div stays in the blue div and If I wanted that, theres no point in this question. My structure was, <red><green/><blue><yellow/></blue></red>

Comment: You can hide and show components based on the mobile layout; suppose you hide the yellow layout and visible another in the mobile layout.

Comment: "without making 2 sets of everything and hiding one of them for desktop and vice versa" Thats exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I thought of it at first but there are two things why I don't want to do that. 1) code redundancy and 2) the yellow div is a react component from npm and for some reason it won't work properly when used twice on the same page(probably fixable but you get the point)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Have the three elements as siblings, in the order you want them displayed on mobile.
2. Detach the blue element's background from its contents (conceptually) - they are not the same thing.
3. Render the yellow and blue (transparent on desktop) elements as right column (using `grid` or `flex`), while placing the blue background under them (I used the parent's `:before`) for positioning the background.
4. I purposefully placed an inline red border on the contents of the blue element, to highlight its position.
5. You're pretty much done. The rest are implementation details.

I challenge you to do it yourself before looking at the solution below.

Key points of the solution below:

- Note the required `position: relative` on the parent and also the `position:relative; z-index: 0` on the *"right-column"* elements (without those rules they're rendered below the `:before`).
- I used `min-height`s here to size the elements (as they're empty) but, once you place content inside them, you could/should remove the `min-height`s.
- You'll probably need to adjust the margins/paddings to suit your needs, once you place real content inside them, but that should be fairly straight-forward.

Here it is:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.red {
  background-color: #ff8584;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: #fff742;
}

.green {
  background-color: #c0ff72;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #72ccff;
}

.red>* {
  min-height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.red>*:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .red {
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template: 'green yellow' auto 'green blue' 1fr / 1fr 1fr;
    min-height: 100vh;
    grid-column-gap: 1rem;
  }
  .red:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #72ccff;
    top: 1rem;
    right: 1rem;
    bottom: 1rem;
    left: calc(50% + .5rem);
  }
  .red>* {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .yellow {
    margin: 1rem 1rem 0;
    grid-area: yellow;
  }
  .green {
    grid-area: green;
  }
  .blue {
    grid-area: blue;
  }
  .yellow,
  .blue {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  .blue {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <div class="yellow"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue" style="border: 1px solid red"></div>
</div>
```

I also wrote an [SCSS version](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/7c21v9o4/), making the background properties `@mixins` and the `$spacer` a variable, so they could be easily replaced.

Comment: This was one of the methods I was fairly certain of after asking the question. Since I'm not used to grids compared to flex, I thought of using something like grid-area and grid-template-areas but from the lead that you gave, I was able to achieve similar results. Thanks for your time! really helped me learn

Answer (score 1):

Even though @tao answered this question with an better answer, I'd also like to provide a less "professional" answer but works great.

My answer uses `grid-template-areas` and media queries. In addition to that, I'm not going to select my own answer as accepted answer(Even though this is what I used in the end)

https://codepen.io/absanthosh/pen/WNRqLYQ?editors=1100

Comment: The "problem" with your answer is it doesn't meet all the requirements of your initial question. The question suggested you're looking for an answer where the background of `details` (which could, in a real life scenario, be an image rather than a plain color) should *"surround"* `search` on desktop view. Your suggested solution does not achieve that at all. And this was one of the trickiest parts of providing an answer: give continuity to that background, while allowing `search` a dynamic height.

Comment: you are right(Both in this comment and the original answer you provided). According to my initial question, I wanted the yellow div in the blue div but the problem was I couldn't  customize any further with the approach you suggested or the code you gave(Because of the lack of experience). Adding or changing anything broke something else. So in my solution, I made the `search` div so that i can have a child div in it and make it look like the `details` div surround the child of `search`. I know this is a "hack" rather than a valid way but I'll change it once I can wrap my head around your ans.

Comment: @tao I have updated my solution to show what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you could do is:

In the HTML code make the order of elements yellow-green-blue, all three as siblings and direct children of red.

For the mobile version there will be no `position` settings necessary, no flex or anything, just regular divs with default (= full) width, with some padding and margins.

For the desktop version make green and blue `inline-block`s, with a little less than 50% width, all taking into account according paddings and margins. Apply `position: relative` to red and `position: absolute` to yellow, which gets a width of around 45% (again, depending on paddings and margins) and a `right` setting that places it where you want it (as a percentage value). The `top` setting for yellow depends on the padding/margins of red and blue.

Comment: If you give yellow `position:absolute` on desktop you'll need js to dynamically adjust the top padding of blue contents. And once you need javascript for it to work with variable amount of content (or for content that has different height based on available width, such as a paragraph), one could argue you can simply append the yellow div to blue on desktop and to red on mobile.

Comment: @tao yellow looks like a header element to me whose height can be pretty much foreseen, so a larger top-padding value for blue can take care of that.

Comment: IMHO, if yellow element's height was constant or foreseen, I don't think OP would have asked the question.